# How to Make a Clock In seconds for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Im Trying to Create a Auto Clicker as a Purchasable item in my idle game and i have looked through all sorts of methods I Tested all Methods **First** Using stock IDE
Then after testing i would go and use replit but every time when i checked to see if it was working and it constantly returned a slowly increasing decimal Of a Ranged rate with it going around .00000119209 per click instead of per second.

```
    adc = float(time.time()-t)
```

Comment: What game engine are you using to write this thing? Any reputable engine is going to have timing functions built-in. You absolutely do *not* want to rely on stock Python timing or thread-freezing functionality, as that will interfere with what the engine is trying to do.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thank You for the feedback i am not using a Engine for this Project and its purely a challenge that i don't wish to use one

Answer (score 0):

A quick Fix for this is that i will just use the Stock Ide